# Can we speed up matrix inversion with ML?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, normal-distribution, covariance

I am working on dynamical system reconstruction in the framework of Variational Autoencoders. In order to estimate the probability distribution of the underlying system p(Z|X) (Z = latent states, X = data which we use to infer parameters), we need to estimate mean and covariance. Therefore I combine estimations from a MLP (encode_mean, encode_cov) with calculations of a Kalman-smoother (h.blk_tridag_chol, h.blk_chol_inv). Here's a code snippet:

```py
        """ cov is actually not the covariance matrix but instead a part of the Matrix 
        used in the Kalman filter to calculate the cholesky decomposition and hence the 
        correct covariance matrix"""

        mean = self.encode_mean(x)
        cov = self.encode_cov(x)

        # compute cholesky decomposition

        self.AA_com, BB_com, lambdaMu_com = self.calculate_cholesky_factors(mean, cov)

        self.the_chol = h.blk_tridag_chol(self.AA_com, BB_com)
        ib_com = h.blk_chol_inv(self.the_chol[0], self.the_chol[1], lambdaMu_com)
        self.mu_z = h.blk_chol_inv(self.the_chol[0], self.the_chol[1], ib_com)
```

I know there are easier ways to estimate covariance and mean, but since we are working on dynamical system reconstruction, a good representation of the covariance matrix with time-dependent elements is very important (time-dependence is implemented by using batches ~x_1 ... x_250). However, the 3 last lines of the code snippet cause my algorithm to be very slow. If you are interested in the exact implementation of h.blk_chol_inv() and h.blk_tridag_chol() I can give further information, but it's basically some matrix multiplications and inversions. I am looking for a method to speed things up.

I was wondering, if we could simply beforehand train two networks to learn the functions h.blk_chol_inv() and h.blk_tridag_chol(), and use these pretrained networks in the algorithm instead? Is this efficient? Can we by pretraining achieve speed ups in matrix inversion? Intuitively I would expect one forward pass through a MLP to be faster than a for-loop Matrix inversion.

Any insights/thoughts appreciated.

Best,
DK